# How do certain companies force payment withdrawal while others can’t?

Tags: debit-card, online-payment

Not sure if this is the right place to ask so let me know otherwise, but it seemed the most appropriate...Some subscription services (Spotify, Netflix for example) can’t process your monthly payment if it makes your account negative, while other services (Gaia, and my office space for instance) can process a monthly payment whether you have the funds or not.

What’s going on behind the scenes that allows this automatic payment to take place regardless of sufficient funds being there or not?

Comment: I can't answer with surety, but a guess: banks often allow _repeating_ chares to execute, because they assume you would want it that way. With the same logic, they decline _one-time_ charges if you have no coverage. It could well be that the companies that you listed that work/fail submit their drafts as repeating/one-time (which is not necessarily correct), and that decides about success/failure?

Comment: interesting. considering both Netflix and Gaia are similarly structured subscription services...do you have any link-able resources?

Comment: Here is an example from amex: https://www.americanexpress.com/us/merchant/cardrefresher.html - the others offer similar services to merchants that care to use them

Comment: Here is Visa: https://usa.visa.com/run-your-business/commercial-solutions/solutions/merchant-processing.html